# Graphing event frequency with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to analyze error frequency on a server cluster to find trends. I've parsed the logs to extract the relevant errors with timestamps. (My data is currently in the format `%b.%d.%H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME`, but converting timestamps is not an issue.) I would like to plot these events on a graph. I've never used gnuplot, so if it is not a good solution, feel free to suggest something else.

All of the gnuplot examples I see (and other graphing solutions for that matter) seem to use data retrieved at regular intervals. CPU usage every 30 seconds, temperature every hour, etc. But for my situation, I might have 300 errors at 8:36 AM, then none for the rest of the day, or constant throughout the day, or... who knows? I'm just trying to get a better visualization.

What I envision as an end result is a graph with three line plots, one per cluster node, showing the frequency of errors (per minute maybe?).

I realize there are larger-scale solutions for this; I'm using Graylog, Logstash, and Kibana on other projects. But this is a one-off, and there have been other situations where I've needed something like this; I'd like to actually invest some time in learning gnuplot. But for now, I'm just trying to get over this hump.

Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to hack something together, but doing it this way is terrible. I used nested for loops to `grep -c` the file to get counts in 10-minute chunks, then saved the results to separate files per node. I was able to generate a graph in gnuplot using that data.

Answer (score 3):

You can plot the frequency using the `smooth frequency` parameter. That replaces all same x-values with a single point having as y-value the sum of all y-values.

In order to get e.g. 5 minute blocks, you must bin the x-data:

```
width = 5*60 # five minutes
bin(x) = (timecolumn(x)/width+0.5)*width
set boxwidth 0.9*width abs
set style fill solid noborder

set timefmt '%b.%d.%H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set yrange [0:*]

host='hostname'
plot 'file' using (bin(1)):(strcol(2) eq host ? 1 : 0) smooth frequency with boxes
```

That works fine with the `boxes` plotting style, but would look strange with `lines`, because you don't get a resampling of the data to a uniform 5 minute grid.

For three host you could iterate that as follows:

```
....
hosts='host1 host2 host3'
plot for [h in hosts] 'file' using (bin(1)):(strcol(2) eq host ? 1 : 0) smooth frequency with boxes title h
```

You can do the filtering also with an external tool like `grep`:

```
hosts = 'host1 host2 host3'
cmd = '< grep ''\b%s\b'' file'
plot for [h in hosts] sprintf(cmd, h) using (bin(1)):(1) smooth frequency with boxes title h
```

In order to resample the data and get a proper line plot, i.e. which doesn't distort the data by interpolating two error bursts, which are one day apart, but nothing happening between them, you'll need an external tool or script.